# bash commands to connect to wifi wpa network in debian

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

I'm trying to connect to my router but having no luck. I'm just missing some simple probably one line of code that I cant find anywhere.

If I write `iwlist wlan0 scan`, it shows over 20+ networks that I can connect to so my wireless card is definitely set up correctly.
For example, I want to connect to a WPA network called "herroprease" with password "wearechinesepeople", so I type

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid herroprease key s:wearechinesepeople
dhclient wlan0
```

However, when I ping `192.168.1.1` (my router) it says that it can't connect.
I've heard that to connect to WPA networks there are extra commands you have to give to bash with `wpa_supplicant`. Is that so? I'm looking for the simplest easy to understand code to get online. Thanks for any help!

Comment: +1 but voted to move to superuser

Comment: Maybe you can try [wicd](http://wicd.sourceforge.net/). Using the command line to setup wifi on Linux is always difficult for me.

Comment: im determined to learn command line! :) im running debian squeeze in text only mode cos i want to learn how to do everything by command line. Wifi connection is proving tough tho >.<

Comment: Then refer to [Debian's wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse), first configure it by modifying `/etc/network/interfaces`. If that succeeds, study the differences of the `iwconfig` output before and after.

Answer (score 3):

For the benefit of all who read this and need help. my solution was `wpa_supplicant` since the network I was trying to connect to was WPA2.

My code was as follows:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid herroprease key s:wearechinesepeople
wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -B -c/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhclient
```

your `wpa_supplicant.conf` file simply needs to contain

```
network={
ssid="herroprease"
psk="wearechinesepeople"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As cyfdecyf pointed out in comments, [Debian's Wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse#wpa_supplicant) contains the information you're looking for, at least for setting up a persistant connection in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.